# Adjusting figures in Grid?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

**First figure:**

```
frames1 = With[{m = 4, r = 1, h = 0.3}, 
Show[Graphics3D[Point[(Append[#1, 0] & ) /@ 
    CirclePoints[1050]]], ParametricPlot3D[
  {r*Cos[\[Phi]], r*Sin[\[Phi]], h*Sin[m*\[Phi]]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Tube[0.03], Axes -> False, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotRange -> 
   1.1*{{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {-h, h}}], Boxed -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 120]];
```

**Second figure:**

```
frames2 = With[{m = 4, r = 1, h = 0.3}, 
   Show[Graphics3D[Point[(Append[#1, 0] & ) /@ 
           CirclePoints[1050]]], ParametricPlot3D[
       {r*Cos[1.2*\[Phi]], r*Sin[1.2*\[Phi]], h*Sin[m*\[Phi]]}, 
       {\[Phi], 0.5*Pi, 2.6*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Tube[0.03], 
       Axes -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
       PlotRange -> 1.1*{{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {-h, h}}], 
     Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 120]];
```

**Third figure:**

```
s1 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.005], Black}], 
FaceForm[GrayLevel[0.01]], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {8, 1.2}, 
 RoundingRadius -> 0.5]}, ImageSize -> 20];

frames3 = Graphics[{Thick, Arrowheads[0.2], 
Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 19}}], Inset[s1, {2, 0}, Automatic, 
 1.01], Inset[s1, {2, 0}, Automatic, 1.01], 
Inset[s1, {1, 1}, Automatic, 1.01], 
Inset[s1, {3, 1}, Automatic, 1.01], 
Inset[s1, {1, 1}, Automatic, 1.01], 
Inset[s1, {3, 4}, Automatic, 1.01], 
Inset[s1, {1, 4}, Automatic, 1.01], 
Inset[s1, {3, 9}, Automatic, 1.01], 
Inset[s1, {1, 9}, Automatic, 1.01], 
Inset[s1, {3, 16}, Automatic, 1.01], 
Inset[s1, {1, 16}, Automatic, 1.01], 
Rotate[Text[Style["Energy", FontFamily -> 
    "Latin Modern Roman", Black, Bold, 10], {-1, 9}], 
 90*Degree], 
Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(0\)]\)", 
  FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", Black, Bold, 10], 
 {2, -0.9}]}, ImageSize -> 120, AspectRatio -> 2.5]


Grid[{{frames1, frames3}, {frames2, SpanFromAbove}}, 
Frame -> All]
```

[image: output]

1. The final output has empty spaces in top left and bottom right
   position. I need to place the three figures symmetrically in the
   same format.
2. I need to add text in first figure frames1, but I am unable to do
   so.

Comment: What text do you want to add?

Comment: (a) at the bottom of the first figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
frames1 = 
  With[{m = 4, r = 1, h = 0.3}, 
   Show[Graphics3D[Point[(Append[#1, 0] &) /@ CirclePoints[1050]], 
     PlotLabel -> "(a)", ImageSize -> {120, 120}], 
    ParametricPlot3D[{r*Cos[\[Phi]], r*Sin[\[Phi]], 
      h*Sin[m*\[Phi]]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Tube[0.03], 
     Axes -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
     PlotRange -> 1.1*{{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {-h, h}}], Boxed -> False]];
frames2 = 
  With[{m = 4, r = 1, h = 0.3}, 
   Show[Graphics3D[Point[(Append[#1, 0] &) /@ CirclePoints[1050]], 
     ImageSize -> {120, 120}], 
    ParametricPlot3D[{r*Cos[1.2*\[Phi]], r*Sin[1.2*\[Phi]], 
      h*Sin[m*\[Phi]]}, {\[Phi], 0.5*Pi, 2.6*Pi}, 
     PlotStyle -> Tube[0.03], Axes -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
     PlotRange -> 1.1*{{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {-h, h}}], Boxed -> False]];
s1 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.005], Black}], 
    FaceForm[GrayLevel[0.01]], 
    Rectangle[{0, 0}, {8, 1.2}, RoundingRadius -> 0.5]}, 
   ImageSize -> 20];

frames3 = 
  Graphics[{Thick, Arrowheads[0.2], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 19}}], 
    Inset[s1, {2, 0}, Automatic, 1.01], 
    Inset[s1, {2, 0}, Automatic, 1.01], 
    Inset[s1, {1, 1}, Automatic, 1.01], 
    Inset[s1, {3, 1}, Automatic, 1.01], 
    Inset[s1, {1, 1}, Automatic, 1.01], 
    Inset[s1, {3, 4}, Automatic, 1.01], 
    Inset[s1, {1, 4}, Automatic, 1.01], 
    Inset[s1, {3, 9}, Automatic, 1.01], 
    Inset[s1, {1, 9}, Automatic, 1.01], 
    Inset[s1, {3, 16}, Automatic, 1.01], 
    Inset[s1, {1, 16}, Automatic, 1.01], 
    Rotate[Text[
      Style["Energy", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", Black, Bold,
        10], {-1, 9}], 90*Degree], 
    Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(0\)]\)", 
      FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", Black, Bold, 
      10], {2, -0.9}]}, ImageSize -> 120, AspectRatio -> 2.5];


Grid[{{frames1, frames3}, {frames2, SpanFromAbove}}, Frame -> All, 
 Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, {Top, Above}}]
```

[image: fig1]